# How to check if phone is charging in RoboVM?

Tags: java, robovm

I would like to know how to check if the phone is charging in Java using RoboVM. Not much else to say, question is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Not really, I googled the problem but came out with nothing so I asked here in the hopes that someone with experience with RoboVM can answer my question. Why the -1 though? I tried searching for it and found nothing, what is the problem with asking about it on stackoverflow?

Comment: I didn't give the minus 1 - I'm not at 125 - but I'd imagine it is because you just asked for an answer without giving an attempt.

Comment: I think that is unfair seeing as there are a lot of questions like that on stack overflow (look at the android section) and some of they have quite the number of upvotes. Either way  I answered my own question but downvoting my question without reason is very unproductive and can only negatively affect those looking for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the question on my own. Here is how you get the battery state in RoboVM:

```
UIDeviceBatteryState batteryState = UIDevice.getCurrentDevice().getBatteryState();
```